# Regular Expression Help: Extracting Fields

Tags: sql, string, oracle, regex-group

In Oracle, I have a database CLOB field I need to extract data from.

The specification looks like:

```
[<br /><b>A:</b><br />Text A which does not contain HTML[<br />]]
[<br /><b>B:</b><br />Text B which does not contain HTML[<br />]]
[<br /><b>C:</b><br />Text C which does not contain HTML[<br />]]
```

Any of the three may be missing or in any order. There is not always a newlines separating the fields, and the fields can contain newlines.

I need:

1. To be able to recognize if the field is in the right format: I think I'm ok as long as I check that the field starts with `<br /><b>`, but a better regex would be awesome.
2. To be able to extract A, B, and/or C sans the "header".

Examples:

| field | Valid | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<br /><b>A:</b><br />Foo<br /> <br /><b>B:</b><br />Bar<br /> <br /><b>C:</b><br />Baz<br />` | Yes | Foo | Bar | Baz |
| `<br /><b>A:</b><br />Foo` | Yes | Foo |  |  |
| `<br /><b>B:</b><br />Bar<br />` | Yes |  | Bar |  |
| `<br /><b>A:</b><br />Foo <br /><b>B:</b><br />Bar<br />` | Yes | Foo | Bar |  |
| `<br /><b>A:</b><br />Foo<br /> <br /><b>C:</b><br />Baz<br />` | Yes | Foo |  | Baz |

Are there any regex gurus who might be able to tell me if/how I could extract A, B, and/or C?

Thanks!

Edit: I've added a SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aae2/14/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked some friends on Facebook as well.

The expression that did what I wanted most -- just to return the values of A, B, and C -- was:

`(.*<b>[ABC]:<.b>)(<br .>)?([^<]*)`

using the parameters

- 1 (start with the beginning of the string)
- 1 (capture the first occurrence of the pattern in the string)
- NULL (no special flags)
- 3 (return the 3rd sub-expression, i.e. the `([^<]*)`

See [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcbcc/1).

Thank you to [pandachelion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3171172/pandachelion) and [spinjector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705042/spinjector) for helping, and my friend Todd Zimnoch for the regexp (and parameters) that did what I wanted most.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on Regex101, set for PCRE/php, with Global enabled, and whether the newlines are there or not. The letter is captured in group #3, and the text in group #6. The whitespace capture and lazy quantification are key to preventing the separate sections from all getting eaten together `(\s*)(.*?)`:

```
((<br \/><b>)([ABC]:)(<\/b><br \/>)(\s*)(.*?)(<br \/>))
```

Tested on:

```
<br /><b>A:</b><br />Text A which does not contain HTML<br />
<br /><b>B:</b><br />Text B which does not contain HTML<br />
<br /><b>C:</b><br />Text C which does not contain HTML<br />
```

Comment: Really close, but the final <br/> is optional...didn't seem to catch that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9aae2/452

Comment: Ok, so the opening `<br />` is required, but the trailing one is not..? That's a bugger. I'll have to fiddle with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with `Oracle` as each engine has it own subtleties but
[here](https://regex101.com/r/7DDUrv/1) it seems to work.

```
(?:\<br \/\>\<b\>[ABC]:\<\/b\>\<br \/\>([^<]+)(?:\<\/b>(?:\<br \>)?)?)?\s*\n?\s*
```

Comment: It will not work in Oracle as Oracle does not support non-capturing groups. Replace `(?:` with just `(` (and do not test Oracle regular expressions on regex101 as it does not support the Oracle syntax - if you are going to test it then use one of the many fiddles that are available for databases.)